# I want to stop click event

Tags: angular, angular8

`<input type="button" (click)="test()" testButton>`

```
test() {
    console.log('test()');
}
```

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[testButton]'
})
export class TestButtonDirective {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    onClick(event: Event) {
        console.log('clickkkkkkkkkkkkkk');
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
}
```

---

▼ Current Result
**clickkkkkkkkkkkkkk**
**test()**

▼ Desired Result
**clickkkkkkkkkkkkkk**

---

*event.stopPropagation();*
*event.preventDefault();*
*event.stopImmediatePropagation();*
is not working

What Should I Do?
I want to control many button events at once.

Comment: It's not that the "click" event is bubbling, it's that several independent listeners are attached to the same element, `stopPropagation` won't help. But would you please elaborate, why do you want, at the same time, to listen to a click via `(click)=` output, and attach a directive that disables that `(click)=`?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's pretty straight forward. Just remove your click event listener `(click)="test()"`

```
<input type="button" testButton>
```

Other than that, if you want to handle the click events anywhere in the application before they are handled by Angular, you can add a click event listener to the window and specify that the event will be processed in the [capture phase](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing#capturing). In the following code snippet, `addEventListener("click", fn, useCapture)` is called with `useCapture` set to true (see the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)).

```
window.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("Global click handler");
}, true);
```

Comment: That's a simple example, and I want to control buttons with various click events all at once through directive.

Comment: What do you mean with 'various' click events. There is only one click event. You can tie as many operations, methods, functions as you want to it. That's the beauty of functional programming.

Comment: If you have another problem, just be specific in your wording.

Comment: For example, let's say you have an A button, a B button, and a C button. I want to check that button's click event via directive. After checking, I want to stop or proceed with the event. Do you understand?

Comment: I would like to handle it inside each button event but I would like to handle it simply via directive

Comment: ```
<button testButton>A</button>
<button testButton>B</button>
<button testButton>C</button>
```
The event is already stopped while executing your directive.

Comment: With `private el: ElementRef` you have the reference to interact with the button itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing $event:

```
<input type="button" (click)="test($event)">

test(event): void {
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Or just remove (click)="test()" from button